# Почему не происходит сжатие flex-элементов?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

Вот код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.second_group_block, .first_group_block {
  display: flex;
}

.first_group_block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вместо `width: 200px;` нужно `flex: 1 1 200px`, и `group_block`-ам прописать `width: 100%`

Comment: @NoSkill то есть вы хотите сказать, что за такое поведение flex-элементов отвечает `width: 200px;` (мол, это значение конкретное и не позволяет flex-элементам быть меньше). Но посмотрите вот этот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/cptLkqfo/)

Comment: а почему тут должно было происходить сжатие элементов?

Comment: @Eva в вашем случае есть еще и "верхний-родительский" элемент, который влияет на "дочерний-родительский".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В твоем случае присутствует еще родительский блок с `display: flex` и выравниванием, из-за этого дочерние блоки имеют фиксированную ширину равную их содержимому что не дает сжиматься блокам внутри. Можно задать `.second_group_block, .first_group_block` `width: 100%`, но тогда пропадет центрирование. По этому предлагаю выравнивать блоки уже внутри дочерних элементов.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.second_group_block, .first_group_block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first_group_block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```